# problem with type in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have defined this type :

```
  type state= L of state_simple * int | N of state * int |  State of int
```

if I only need the integer of "State" What should I do?

here is the code:

```
   let prove state ch a =

  (*"state" is of type State st, i need the integer st*)
   let (_,p,suc,_) =game.(i) in

   let x = ref[] in
   let y = ref(Variable a.(suc.(0)) )in
   let l = Array.length suc in 

   x :=a.(suc.(0)) :: !x;

   if (p=0) then 
      (if (l <> 1) then
           (for i=1 to l-1 do 
               x := ((a.(suc.(i))) :: !x)
           done;

  !x;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first recommend trying to better understand immutability and functional techniques as you don't need references for a lot of what you are doing.  Here is how I would get the integer:

```
let prove st ch a =

  let i = match st with
   | State x -> x
   | L _ | N _ -> assert false (* or raise an exception *)
  in
   let (_,p,suc,_) =game.(i) in

   let x = ref[] in
   let y = ref(Variable a.(suc.(0)) )in (* are you using y anywhere? *)
   let l = Array.length suc in 

   x :=a.(suc.(0)) :: !x;

   if (p=0) then 
      (if (l <> 1) then
           (for i=1 to l-1 do 
               x := ((a.(suc.(i))) :: !x)
           done;

  !x;;
```

You don't seem to be using y, I'm not sure if that's due to a typo or something else.  Also you can construct your list `x` functionally using recursion:

```
let prove st ch a =

  let i = match st with
   | State x -> x
   | L _ -> assert false (* or raise an exception *)
   | N _ -> assert false
  in
   let (_,p,suc,_) =game.(i) in

   let l = Array.length suc in 

   let rec loop x lst =
     if x >= l then
       lst
     else
       loop (x+1) (a.(suc.(i)) :: lst)
   in
   if (p=0) && (l <> 1) then 
     loop 1 [a.(suc.(0))]
   else
     []
```

EDIT: After reading through some comments, it sounds like you are confused about what constitutes a type in OCaml.

```
type state= L of state_simple * int | N of state * int |  State of int
```

creates a new type called `state`.  `State(2)` and `N(State(3), 2)` *have the same type, but different values.*  If I write a function with the signature `val f : state -> int` (that is, a function named `f` that takes a `state` and returns an `int`), I can pass that function `State(2)` **or** `N(N(State(3), 4), 2)` or anything else.

Since you want the function `prove` to only accept a `state` whose value is `State(x)`, you might want to rethink the way you are calling `prove`.  Maybe `prove` should just take an `int` instead of a `state`, and the caller of `prove` can do the pattern matching.

If this is too cumbersome (`prove` is called in multiple places) then having the match statement in the function makes sense, as long as bad matches (`L_` and 'N_') are handled properly.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood You correctly, something like:

```
match foo with
| State i -> do_something_with_integer i
| _ -> ()
```

Comment: What does it mean :  | _ -> ()  to say that in other cases should not do anything?

Comment: "_" means a wildcard, or "any value"; "()" is unit, or empty function; the whole expression can be translated to "do nothing on any other match"

Comment: It returns () in cases where State i doesn't match.  That means whatever you do in do_something_with_integer i must also return ().

Comment: @Antonio:  as @stonemetal said, return type of both matches should be the same

Comment: However, given that after this statement there are written instructions, gives me an error that says I have to return a value of type unit instead of the value that should retun

Comment: @Antonio: and what do You return in first match?

Comment: @barti_ddu  let st = ref (-1) in
   
   match state with
   | State i -> st:=i;
   | _ -> ();
because I need to work with the integer of "State"

Comment: @Antonio; what if that function isn't passed the value State? That's the point. If you are _certain_ that it will _never_ happen, you can add an `assert false`, but it is also noteworthy to avoid using `_`. Instead, `N _ | L _ -> assert false`.

Comment: Get rid of the semi-colon after `st:=i`.  Also, I'd recommend editing your question and posting a little bit more code.

Comment: @Antonio: correct, You shoud assign State, not int; like this `st := (State i)`

Comment: @Antonio: and same with the first assignment: `let st = ref (State (-1))`

Comment: @barti_ddu: but so encapsulates again the integer.but I need

Comment: In Ocaml a function may only have one return type. In this case both branches of the pattern match must return a value of the same type.  weather it passes through the unused variants of state or you go with an option type is up to you.

Comment: @Antonio: I have a feeling that You are mixing records with variant types (correct me, if I'm wrong). In the first place why did You create *state* type, what is its purpose?